# How many papers about AI / ML were published in the recent years?

Tags: machine-learning, papers

I am trying to formulate an argument at work saying the disruption in AI/ML is very high and that it is hard to stay "state of the art". I would like to support that hypothesis by numbers.

**Question:**

How many papers were published in 2018-2020 related to AI (or if that is too generic: ML)?

Comment: There are several ML conferences and journals. You can count the number of papers published in the most notable conferences, such as NeurIPS, to provide a lower bound on the number of published papers. In any case, it's possible that there's some tool that does this automatically.